# Nearest Neighbor rendering in UWP

Tags: c#, graphics, uwp

I'm trying to zoom images in UWP by using nearest neighbor scaling.
In WPF i used `RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(image, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);`. How can I get the same result but in UWP?

[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120417/bitmap-smoothing-in-uwp

Answer (score 2):

> In WPF i used RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(image, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);. How can I get the same result but in UWP?

In uwp, [`BitmapTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmaptransform) can be used for scaling images. To getting the same effects as you got by using `BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor` in WPF, you need to use [`BitmapInterpolationMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapinterpolationmode) which has `NearestNeighbor` value.

Example code you can reference follows:

```
private async Task<IStorageFile> CreateNewImage(StorageFile sourceFile, int requestedMinSide, StorageFile resizedImageFile)
{
    var imageStream = await sourceFile.OpenReadAsync();
    var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
    var originalPixelWidth = decoder.PixelWidth;
    var originalPixelHeight = decoder.PixelHeight;
    using (imageStream)
    {
        using (var resizedStream = await resizedImageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(resizedStream, decoder);
            double widthRatio = (double)requestedMinSide / originalPixelWidth;
            double heightRatio = (double)requestedMinSide / originalPixelHeight;
            uint aspectHeight = (uint)requestedMinSide;
            uint aspectWidth = (uint)requestedMinSide;
            uint cropX = 0, cropY = 0;
            var scaledSize = (uint)requestedMinSide;
            aspectHeight = (uint)(widthRatio * originalPixelHeight);
            cropY = (aspectHeight - aspectWidth) / 2;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = aspectHeight;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = aspectWidth;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.Bounds = new BitmapBounds()
            {
                Width = scaledSize,
                Height = scaledSize,
                X = cropX,
                Y = cropY,
            };
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
    return resizedImageFile;
}
```